# Libres3 Access Denied from Meteor Slingshot

Tags: meteor, amazon-s3, meteor-slingshot

I have a 3-node cluster with SX running on Ubuntu v14.04.5 LTS with ports 80 & 443 and Libres3 running on the same servers with ports 8008 & 8443.

> libres3                             1.3-1-1~wheezy
>
> sx                                  2.1-1-1~wheezy

s3cmd info s3://test-dev

> s3://test-dev/ (bucket):    Location:  us-east-1    Payer:
>   BucketOwner    Expiration Rule: none    policy:    {   "Version":
>   "2012-10-17",   "Statement": [
>       {
>         "Effect": "Allow",
>         "Principal": "*",
>         "Action": "s3:GetObject",
>         "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-dev/*"
>       }   ] }    cors:      *OptionPUTPOSTGETHEAD3000**    ACL:       admin: FULL_CONTROL    ACL:       test: FULL_CONTROL

I'm trying to put files from a Meteor application using the Slingshot package: https://github.com/CulturalMe/meteor-slingshot

but getting

> 'Access Denied':
>   "Sep  6 11:10:46: main: Replying with code 403: Access Deniedlibres3_1ff0aa644987498111ea4c91bca7b532_13817_587_1473174646.21`AccessDenied`
>   "

I can use S3 Browser and Cloudberry Explorer with the same credentials and access the buckets no problem.

Any thoughts or directions to solve putting files from the web?
Thanks,
-Matt

Answer (score 0):

```
{ "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": 
   [
      {  "Effect":"Allow", 
         "Principal": "", 
         "Action": "s3:GetObject", 
         "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-dev/*" 
      }
   ] 
}
```

You need to add **"*"** after **"test-dev/"**

Comment: hi,  thanks for the suggestion, but I think the '*' got stripped out while pasting here.  For now, we've ended up signing the requests because we found that using SHA1 in a BASH script worked but not from a BASH script that used HMAC-SHA256 (Amazon Sigv4).  I'll need to re-visit it again.